# Regression on unevenly distributed high dimensional dataset

Tags: regression, feature-selection, high-dimensional, synthetic-data, neuroscience

I have a very high dimensional (20K+ hand engineered features) biological dataset to predict a single continuous output variable (such as a mental state exam scores for a dementia patient). The output score can range between 0-90 and the scores are very unevenly distributed between intervals. For example, there can be many patients with a score between (0,1) and no patients with a score between, say, (40-45). Based on previous posts on stackexchange and elsewhere, i have tried using bin scatter based prediction, spline based regression, kernel ridge regressions so far with very poor results (low or even negative test R2 scores).

I think that poor feature reduction techniques combined with severe data imbalance in different score intervals leads to really poor test r2 accuracies. Given that the dataset is biological, we used a simple 2 sample t-test for feature elimination with p < 0.05.

Is it possible to generate synthetic data for this dataset that can address the data imbalance issue ? If yes, how can such data be generated ? Libraries like imblearn SMOTE generate synthetic data for classification problems. I am not familiar with generating synthetic data for regression problems. How is this done (an example in python/matlab will be helpful), especially in a high dimensional setting ?

[This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-49656-2.pdf) mentions the use of CRBMs to generate synthetic data, although, they address a more advanced version of my problem (prediction of a multi variable output indicating disease progression over a time period).

Comment: I don't think data imbalance is the problem here. What if you try classification for basically healthy people and purple with dementia? Or what if you get rid of the healthy people and try to predict the score in the rest?

Comment: @rep_ho thanks for the comment.yes,it is a reasonable observation,given that a healthy patient's data will be quite different from an unhealthy one's.no? let me try this method again and get back.btw,i found an excellent library in R(UBL) for synthetic data generation in regression problems.it's also on github!